# Is it possible to 'require' multiple data files in 'params' Parameter in Protractor conf

Tags: protractor

I am using the `params : require('../test-data/test_data.json'),` in conf.js to read the JSON Test Data for the Test.

However, I want to include more than one JSON file in the `params`? If yes, then how can the same be used?

Regards,
Sakshi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's probably a better idea to pass the filepaths that you want in your params in the config, and actually doing the merge/processing in a helper file. But if your question is asking how to merge 2 objects in javascript: [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Comment: params : { data1: require('../test-data/some_data.json'), data2: require('../test-data/some_other_data.json') },    Use in spec as: browser.params.data1 OR browser.params.data2